Problem loading TensorFlow Lite model into Android application
Problem loading TensorFlow Lite model into Android application.
I used many repositories as an example of an application with a .tflite format model (specifically for the segmentation task), they all work and launch, but as soon as I load my model, the application either crashes or simply does not work.
I used such repositories as examples: TensorFlow Lite Example, MLkit, D2GO (it had a .pt format, and I also couldn’t load my model). After a while I realized that my model was missing metadata. I don't know if they are needed there or not, but I also tried to add them or train the model through the official Tensorflow documentation, all of which were unsuccessful. Can anyone tell me how I can run my model on Android? TF version 2.17.0

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Need more details, recently I have successfully integrated tensorflow lite model in android for image classification and it is working fine and that too for TF version 2.17.0. Let me know if you need for image classifications. Right now, I m trying to use mobileBERT question answer model and struggling to implement it..

RajeshKumar_ I'm trying to implement a segmentation task, so far I've settled on filling in the metadata

I don't know which model you are using. I'm guessing something like YOLO segmentation models. So your best bet is to use tflite_flutter package. You can run your model but decoding your outputs will be a challenge.

Hi. Can you place the error you are getting? TensorFlow Lite (LiteRT now) does not need metadata but ML kit and MediaPipe do need them.

Hello Farmaker, the official TensorFlow Lite documentation indicates that metadata that is required when connecting, just adding metadata solved my problem of using the model in Android
